# Is it okay to ask colleagues for upvotes?

Tags: discussion, voting, upvotes

So I hypothetically wrote an answer, and I think it's the best answer.

Is it okay for me to ask my colleagues to review my answer and upvote it if they agree with it?

I can't tell whether the community would benefit from the additional traffic and from professionals I work with adding their expert opinions, or whether there are rules about purposefully directing people to my answer because I wrote it, when they probably wouldn't have seen it otherwise.

There may be no practical way of detecting/enforcing/reporting this, but is this action acceptable, encouraged, or discouraged within the ethos of the SO community?

Comment: if they agree with it AND find it useful

Comment: Note that multiple upvotes from the same IP is likely to be flagged as potential sock-puppeting...even though it seems that this is done in good faith. Frankly, I wouldn't ask...there is the potential for the votes to be based on YOU and not the actual answer.

Comment: @Louis - I did search for this question! I guess I didn't think of asking my friends, just my colleagues ;)

Comment: It's totally cool.  You should have them upvote all your stuff.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In a word, no.

You asked,

> Is it okay for me to ask my colleagues to review my answer and upvote it if they agree with it?

You're welcome to ask colleagues to *review* your answer, but you should not encourage upvoting by people you know. To quote from a warning we sometimes have to send people:

> While we encourage everyone to upvote great posts, the motivation for doing so needs to be anchored in the merits of the *post*, **not the person who wrote it.** ...
>
> Stack Exchange works by ensuring that the best information rises to the top. Voting specifically for content that benefits your friends, family or colleagues unfairly skews that system, and continuing to do so can result in a lengthy suspension for all involved.
>
> ... The system has processes in place to detect various types of voting between groups of users, so if you know anyone who may be voting for your stuff in kind, please ask them to refrain before the system detects such activity....
>
> ...[C]ontinued activity of this sort can result in a prolonged suspension for all involved....

It's fine to send a friend or colleague a link to a post when that person has the same issue. But please don't ask for upvotes. Users will upvote if they feel it's appropriate; asking for it pressures them to do so. That distorts the voting patterns. And that means the site as a whole is less useful to everyone.